# "This Feature is not available on this device" getting this error While asking DND permission

Tags: android, performance, android-permissions

"This Feature is not available on this device" While asking DND permission

How can we check whether the device has DND feature or not or any other solution please..

I am using below code to get DND permission

```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M
                                            && !notificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()) {

 Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

The device I am using has Oreo and nougat.

[image]

Comment: Did someone find a workaround for this? I cant reproduce it atm, but I guess if we're lucky, we can set the permission without getting an exception for these specific devices, like they are < M version. If not, the API itself is contradictory/incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

This feature doesn't seems to be available on all versions of Oreo. For example on "Oreo Go Edition" on a Wiko Lenny 5, I don't have it either.

Comment: May be, but I am getting this message in other Devices also not only in Go Edition.